# Laravel : email send multiples times to one user

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, sendmail

I want send email to many users in one time but in this case the mail is sending multiple times to one user it self.

Try to email each person one time only(not spam the users)
Its didnt work with this method anyone can help n this thing again.

```php
    public function create() 
    {
        $users = User::where('user_type', 2)->get();
        $auto_email_templates = AutoEmailTemplate::all();

        foreach ($users as $user) {
            foreach($auto_email_templates as $mail){

                if( $user->created_at < Carbon::now()->subDays($mail->days)){

                    Mail::to($user->email)->send(new Automail($mail));
                    $mail = new EmailSave;
                    $mail->user_id = $user->id;
                    $mail->email_id =$mail->id;
                    $mail->save();
                }
            }   
        }       
    }

public function create() 
    {
        $users = User::where('user_type', 2)->get();
        $auto_email_templates=AutoEmailTemplate::all();


        foreach($auto_email_templates as $mail) {
            foreach ($users as $user) {


                if( $user->created_at < Carbon::now()->subDays($mail->days)){

                    if (EmailSave::where('email_id', '=', Input::get('email_id'))->exists()) {
                        Mail::to($user->email)->send(new Automail($mail));
                    }
                   else {  
                       return false;
                   }               

                    $mail = new EmailSave;
                    $mail->user_id = $user->id;
                    $mail->email_id =$mail->id;
                    $mail->save();

                }
```

Comment: You are having too loops. Inner loop also looping again. So if there are  data in `$auto_email_template ` then same email will be send twice.

Comment: Because you are using nested foreach loop that is why you are facing this issue.

Comment: What do you want to do with foreach($auto_email_templates as $mail)?

Comment: @Sehdev thats what he should explain to us

Comment: @Sehdev Foreach($auto_email_templates as $mail) is the template is sending to the email. basically, im trying to do send auto mail to all users. So, the auto_email_templates is a template to send the email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using nested foreach loop that is why you are facing this issue. If you want to send each template to each user then you can simply swap your loops like:

```
public function create() 
{
    $users = User::where('user_type', 2)->get();
    $auto_email_templates=AutoEmailTemplate::all();



  foreach($auto_email_templates as $mail){ 
       foreach ($users as $user) { // add this to here

            if( $user->created_at < Carbon::now()->subDays($mail->days)){

                Mail::to($user->email)->send(new Automail($mail));


                $mail = new EmailSave;
                $mail->user_id = $user->id;
                $mail->email_id =$mail->id;
                $mail->save();

            }
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you so much. its working sir. i got another question. How send mail one time only for each user. Can help me to do ?

Comment: @NavanithaMoorthy for that, you can't add another enum column in your table, to check that Mail has already sent or not, If not then send it.

Comment: @talha F I already created a new table to check the email has sent or not. That is working perfectly now. But I want make sure that email should sent again to same user.